# Is it possible to add tracking to Hubspot form submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, google-analytics, hubspot

Does anyone know if tracking code can be added to the submit button in a Hubspot form? I've tried adding the tracking code using the `onFormSubmit` attribute but I'm not getting any tracking results for the submit button clicks. Maybe I have the code incorrectly formatted.? I've included my code below for reference. I've removed the portal and form ids for security reasons.

Thanks!

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="//js.hsforms.net/forms/v2-legacy.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="//js.hsforms.net/forms/v2.js"></script>
<script>
hbspt.forms.create({ 
css: '',
cssClass:'.hs-form fieldset {max-width: 100%;}',
portalId: '',
formId: '',
inlineMessage: '<iframe style="width:100%; height:800px;" scrolling="auto" src="URL goes here"></iframe>',
onFormSubmit: 'mmConversionTag(704048, this, "_self"); ga("send","event","button","click","product distributors")'
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

onFormSubmit is a callback, you should wrap it in an anonymous function instead of passing a string:

```
 hbspt.forms.create({ 
    css: '',
    cssClass:'.hs-form fieldset {max-width: 100%;}',
    portalId: '',
    formId: '',
    inlineMessage: '<iframe style="width:100%; height:800px;" scrolling="auto" src="URL goes here"></iframe>',
    onFormSubmit: function(){
       mmConversionTag(704048, this, "_self");
       ga("send","event","button","click","product distributors");
    }
 });
```